# Passing the limit inside the Laurent series to prove result regarding isolated singularities

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am reading Robert Ash's Complex Variables. In [Theorem 4.1.5](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV4.pdf) of the book, the authors are proving the following theorem:

Suppose that $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$. Suppose that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$. We need to show that $f(z)$ approaches a finite limit.

---

Here's what the authors say:

Since $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, we can write
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n \text{ for } z \in D'(z_0 , r)
\end{equation*}
for some unique sequence $(a_n)$ and some $r>0$.

Then the authors pass the limit and say that:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = a_0.
\end{equation*}

I think there's a gap that I need to fill, that is,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n \right) \stackrel{(?)}{=}   \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{z\to z_0} a_n (z-z_0)^n \right) = a_0.
\end{equation*}

I know that the Laurent series converges uniformly on compact subsets on $D'(z_0, r)$. If I could find a compact subset of $D' (z_0, r)$ whose limit point is $z_0$ then I can apply Dominated Convergence Theorem (or a weaker result) to pass the limit inside the sum.

However, I could not find a compact subset of $D' (z_0,r)$ whose limit point of $z_0$. Is there any  alternative way to pass this limit inside the sum?

Comment: closure of $D'(z_0, r/2)$ where?

Comment: closure of $D'(z_0, r/2)$ in $\mathbb C$ is $\{ z \in \mathbb C : \lvert z-z_0 \rvert \le r/2 \}$ and OTOH,  closure of $D'(z_0, r/2)$ in $D'(z_0 ,r)$ is $\{ z \in \mathbb C : 0< \lvert z-z_0 \rvert \le r/2 \}$ and the latter is not compact.

Comment: It's not helpful to not explain the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ with radius of convergence $\rho>0$, its sum is a continuous function on $D(z_0,\rho)$. In particular, it is continuous at $z_0$, and therefore$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n=\left.\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n\right|_{z=z_0}=a_0.$$